# query with FILTER(?document = "uriNode") returns no results

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena

I am executing the SPARQL query below with Jena, where `uriNode` is a `String` representing a `URI`, but this query doesn't give me any results.  I've already checked the database and this `URI` does exist there.  What's the problem?

```java
String queryString2 = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> " +
                    "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> SELECT ?author WHERE { " +
                    "?document dc:creator ?author." +
                    "FILTER (?document = \"" + uriNode + "\" ). }";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AndyS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19893320/1281433) is right, insofar as that you're currently checking whether `?document` is some particular *string*.  Since strings (and more generally, literals) can't be the subject of triples in RDF, you'll never get any solutions this way. You actually need to check whether it's a particular URI.  You could do that with a `filter` like this

```
FILTER( ?document = <http://example.org/node> )
```

but that's really *very* wasteful, because a query like the following (based on yours) is retrieving *all* the things with `dc:creator`s and then throwing most of them out.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
SELECT ?author WHERE {
  ?document dc:creator ?author.
  FILTER (?document = <http://example.org/node> ).
}
```

It's *literally* like asking a library catalog for a list of all the books and their authors, and then going through them one by one and discarding the results for all but one book.  A much more efficient solution would be to ask for the `dc:creator` of the thing that you actually care about, because this will only select the data that you want, and it won't have to do any filtering:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
SELECT ?author WHERE {
  <http://example.org/node> dc:creator ?author.
}
```

You can do a similar thing if you needed, e.g., to select documents with a specific title;  use a query like this:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
SELECT ?document WHERE {
  ?document dc:title "Reply to Hayne" .
  # or, if language tags are in use, 
  # ?document dc:title "Reply to Hayne"@en
}
```

Comment: Your answer makes a good point, however any decent SPARQL optimiser will turn the first query into the second

Comment: @Joshua Taylor Yes, thats what I need! But I need help! Because I have a search page, where the user writes a "title" of a document he wants to look for, with a query like this:  SELECT ?document WHERE { ?document dc:title ?title.?document dc:subject ?subject." "FILTER (?title = \"" + this.getTitle() + "\" ). }";

Comment: @Luciane The same thing holds; just use the `select ... where { ?document dc:title \""+this.getTtile()+"\" . }`.  It would actually be better to start using [parameterized SPARQL strings](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ParameterizedSparqlString.html) here.  More importantly, though, you should at least skim through the [SPARQL 1.1 Query](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) recommendation and familiarize yourself with SPARQL grammar.  These are relatively basic questions about SPARQL syntax, and the recommendationhas lots of examples.

Comment: @Luciane I've updated my answer with a clearer example of putting the literal title in the query.  Note that questions on StackOverflow should generally be self contained, and that separate questions should be asked as separate questions.  This one was close enough, though, that I felt OK updating the answer for it. SPARQL is a graph query language, and the query itself is a _pattern_ that needs to match the structure of the data. When you have specific values that need to be in the data, the easiest way to ensure it is not through the use of a `filter`, but by putting it the pattern directly.

Comment: Thank you, @JoshuaTaylor! Sorry, my last comment above is incomplete, because it's too big to be a comment, so I'm going to post another question and write the link here later.

Comment: @RobV I'm glad to hear that!  (I indirectly _use_ SPARQL optimizers all the time, I suppose, but I don't often sit down to consider what they are and aren't capable of.)  Is it just as likely that a filter like `filter( ?document = ... | ?document = ... )` would get optimized into the equivalent `values ?document { ... ... }`?

Comment: Current optimisers may optimise queries of that form but likely not into `VALUES` since `VALUES` is a relatively new construct.  Often what is done (and is more efficient) is to generate `{ } UNION { }` where each branch of the `UNION` has one possibly value for the variable substituted into it

Answer (score 3):

You are testing whether `?document` is the string `?uriNode`, not testing as a URI.

```
FILTER (?document = <" + uriNode + ">" )
```

Comment: True, but Joshua gives better advice