# How to improve slow query using FILTER (?id IN ( … ) )

Tags: performance, rdf, sparql

I just started using SPARQL, and I'm trying to create a query that retrieves all information where an  id has one of a number of predefined values? I have something like this :

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
    ?id ?property ?value .
    ?value a ?type .
    ?type rdfs:label ?type_value .
    FILTER ( ?id IN (<id1>,<idi>,<idn> ) )
}
```

The problem I've been running into is the query gets really slow when the list of ids gets increasingly large. I intuitively think there's a better way to write this query, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to create this kind of query.  I'm thinking along the lines of something like this:

```
SELECT * 
WHERE {
    <id_value> ?property ?value .
    ?value a ?type .
    ?type rdfs:label ?type_value .
}
```

where it retrieves all values only for the multiple ids, eliminating the filtering of results at the end, but I can't figure out how to write the query so that it returns all values for an id_value. when I add another line for another id_value, it filters out other values I'm expecting, so I think I'm writing it incorrectly.  How can I do this?

Comment: It looks like I'll eventually be able to upgrade to virtuoso v.7, so I will try this method once I can get the upgrade. Thanks everyone. I'll post my findings once I do so!

Comment: Thanks everyone! The Values clause made a huge difference - a 14 second query down to 2-4 seconds. (still looking for ways to optimize, now looking at virtuoso settings to see if there's something I can change to speed that up, but it's very promising!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `values`, you can write:

```sql
SELECT * WHERE {
  values ?id { <id1> <idi> <idn> }
  ?id ?property ?value .
  ?value a ?type .
  ?type rdfs:label ?type_value .
}
```

The SPARQL 1.1 says about [`values`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data):

> Data can be directly written in a graph pattern or added to a query
>   using VALUES. VALUES provides inline data as a solution sequence which
>   are combined with the results of query evaluation by a join operation.
>   It can be used by an application to provide specific requirements on
>   query results and also by SPARQL query engine implementations that
>   provide federated query through the SERVICE keyword to send a more
>   constrained query to a remote query service.

One of the examples is actually very close to what you've already got:

```sql
PREFIX dc:   <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> 
PREFIX :     <http://example.org/book/> 
PREFIX ns:   <http://example.org/ns#> 

SELECT ?book ?title ?price
{
   VALUES ?book { :book1 :book3 }
   ?book dc:title ?title ;
         ns:price ?price .
}
```

Comment: Thanks...unfortunately, the current sparql endpoint I'm using (virtuoso 6.1.6) doesn't support that clause. I guess I'll see what I can do about upgrading...

Comment: @harmlessdragon Hm, that does complicate things.  Although it would make your _query_ longer, can you try `{ <id1> ... } union ... union { <idn> ... }` as a comparison, and see how it performs?  Although it will be longer textually, the performance should be much better, since you'll only be getting the results you want.

Comment: Already tried that too haha...and it turned out a little longer than using the `FILTER` clause.

Comment: @harmlessdragon Aww, that's painful.  :(

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [`VALUES`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data) clause instead like so:

```
SELECT * 
WHERE {
    VALUES ?id { ...list of ids... }
    ?id ?property ?value .
    ?value a ?type .
    ?type rdfs:label ?type_value .
}
```

This should hopefully be much more efficient that using the `FILTER` approach.

Comment: In some comments on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19897359/1281433), we (you and I) had a bit of discussion about `FILTER( ?document = ... || ?document = ... )` getting optimized into a `union` based query (but I think one of the comments has since been deleted).  Is there any reason that `?id in ( ... )` shouldn't get optimized the same way?

Comment: I came across the values clause earlier. Unfortunately, the current sparql endpoint I'm using (virtuoso 6.1.6) doesn't support that clause. I guess I'll see what I can do about upgrading...

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor In ARQ it does, `?id IN ( )` is transformed into the equivalent `?id == <x> || ?id == <y>` etc. and then that gets transformed into a `UNION`.  However optimisers will differ wildly in their behaviour particularly in the case of something like Virtuoso where it is compiling the SPARQL into SQL