# Best Practices on querying for multiple properties of a resource in the same SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, jena

On my database, I have triples like:

```
DocumentUri -> dc.title -> title 
DocumentUri -> dc.language -> language 
DocumentUri -> dc.description -> description 
DocumentUri -> dc.creator -> AuthorUri
```

I'd like to be able to search for a `document`title and then get all the properties from all the documents matching the title search.

I'm trying to do that with `Jena` and `SPARQL`. I made a query that receives a `title` to get the Uris from the documents that have the given title. That's the method, it gets the uris returned and store them in a list called `webDocumentListInicial`:

```
public void searchUriByTitle() {
        RDFNode documentUriNode;

        String queryString = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> " +
                "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> SELECT ?document WHERE { " +
                "?document dc:title ?title." +
                "FILTER (?title = \"" + this.getTitle() + "\" ). }";

        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);

        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, databaseModel);
        ResultSet results =  qe.execSelect();

        while( results.hasNext() ) {

           QuerySolution querySolution = results.next();
           documentUriNode = querySolution.get("document");

           WebDocument document = new WebDocument(documentUriNode.toString());
          this.webDocumentListInicial.add(document);

        }

        qe.close();  
    }
```

To get the document's creator I made another query, because in this case tha `value` from the triple is another resource. Here, I iterate the `list` of document URIs that was filled in the method above.

```
public void searchAuthorByTitle() {
    for(  WebDocument doc : this.webDocumentListInicial ) {
    RDFNode authorUriNode;

    String queryString = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> " +
            "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> SELECT ?author WHERE { " +
            "?document dc:creator ?author." +
            "FILTER (?document = <" + doc.getUri() + "> ). }";

    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);

    QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, databaseModel);
    ResultSet results =  qe.execSelect();

    while( results.hasNext() ) {

       QuerySolution querySolution = results.next();
       authorUriNode = querySolution.get("author");

       WebAuthor author; 
       author = this.searchAuthorProperties(authorUriNode.toString(), new WebAuthor(authorUriNode.toString()) );

       doc.addAuthor(author);
    }
    qe.close();  
    }
}
```

And to get the other document properties, I do like in the example below, where I iterate the `list` that was filled in the first method I showed above.

```
public void searchDescription() {

        for( WebDocument doc : this.webDocumentListInicial ) {
            String description = "";

            Resource resource = ResourceFactory.createResource(doc.getUri());
            StmtIterator descriptionStmtIt = databaseModel.listStatements(resource, DC.description,(RDFNode) null);

            while( descriptionStmtIt.hasNext() ) {
                description = descriptionStmtIt.next().getObject().toString();
            }
            doc.setDescription(description);
        } 

    }
```

This way I'm handling with the data isn't very productive because I need a different query for each property I get.

Is it possible to make only one query to get the document URI and all the other  document's properties at once? I tried that once, like this:

```
String queryString = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> " +
                "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> SELECT ?document ?description " +
                "?language ?author  WHERE { " +
                "?document dc:title ?title." +
                "?document dc.language ?language" +
                "?document dc.description ?description" +
                "?document dc.creator ?author" +
                "FILTER (?title = \"" + this.getTitle() + "\" ). }";
```

But when I had more than one document matching the given title, it was difficult to know which properties returned belonged to each document.

Thank you!!

Comment: Why are you still doing things like `FILTER (?document = <" + doc.getUri() + "> )`?  Answers to you previous question, [query with FILTER(?document = “uriNode”) returns no results](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19890512/1281433), discussed the problems with that…

Comment: Sorry IM dealing with so many problems at the same time and that's so new for me...thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Building a better query

It sounds like you're doing a lot more work than you need to.  If you have data like this:

```
@prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/20436820/1281433/>

:doc1 :title "Title1" ; :author :author1 ; :date "date-1" .
:doc2 :title "Title2" ; :author :author2 ; :date "date-2" .
:doc3 :title "Title3" ; :author :author3 ; :date "date-3" .
:doc4 :title "Title4" ; :author :author4 ; :date "date-4" .
:doc5 :title "Title5" ; :author :author5 ; :date "date-5" .
```

And a list of titles, say `"Title1" "Title4" "Title5"` and you want retrieve the resource of the document with each title, along with the associated author and date, you can use a query like this:

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/20436820/1281433/>

select ?document ?author ?date where {
  values ?title { "Title1" "Title4" "Title5" }

  ?document :title ?title ;
            :author ?author ;
            :date ?date .
}
```

You'll get results like this in one ResultSet.  There's no need to make multiple queries.

```
----------------------------------
| document | author   | date     |
==================================
| :doc1    | :author1 | "date-1" |
| :doc4    | :author4 | "date-4" |
| :doc5    | :author5 | "date-5" |
----------------------------------
```

### Building a map of the results

Based on your comments, it sounds like you need to construct some other kind of associative structure from the ResultSet.  Here's one way that you could construct a `Map<RDFNode,Map<String,RDFNode>>` that takes each document IRI to another map that takes each of the variable named to the associated value.

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode;

public class HashedResultsExample {

    final static String DATA =
            "@prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/20436820/1281433/>\n" +
            "\n" +
            ":doc1 :title 'Title1' ; :author :author1 ; :date 'date-1' .\n" +
            ":doc2 :title 'Title2' ; :author :author2 ; :date 'date-2' .\n" +
            ":doc3 :title 'Title3' ; :author :author3 ; :date 'date-3' .\n" +
            ":doc4 :title 'Title4' ; :author :author4 ; :date 'date-4' .\n" +
            ":doc5 :title 'Title5' ; :author :author5 ; :date 'date-5' .\n" ;

    final static String QUERY = 
            "prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/20436820/1281433/>\n" +
            "select ?document ?author ?date where {\n" +
            "  values ?title { \"Title1\" \"Title4\" \"Title5\" }\n" +
            "  ?document :title ?title ; :author ?author ; :date ?date .\n" +
            "}" ;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        try ( final InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream( DATA.getBytes() )) {
            model.read( in, null, "TTL" );
        }

        final ResultSet rs = QueryExecutionFactory.create( QUERY, model ).execSelect();
        final Map<RDFNode,Map<String,RDFNode>> map = new HashMap<>();

        while ( rs.hasNext() ) {
            final QuerySolution qs = rs.next();
            final Map<String,RDFNode> rowMap = new HashMap<>();
            for ( final Iterator<String> varNames = qs.varNames(); varNames.hasNext(); ) {
                final String varName = varNames.next();
                rowMap.put( varName, qs.get( varName ));
            }
            map.put( qs.get( "document" ), rowMap );
        }

        System.out.println( map );
    }
}
```

The output (since the map is printed at the end) with some newlines for readability is:

```
{http://stackoverflow.com/q/20436820/1281433/doc4=
 {author=http://stackoverflow.com/q/20436820/1281433/author4,
  document=http://stackoverflow.com/q/20436820/1281433/doc4,
  date=date-4},
 http://stackoverflow.com/q/20436820/1281433/doc1=
 {author=http://stackoverflow.com/q/20436820/1281433/author1,
  document=http://stackoverflow.com/q/20436820/1281433/doc1,
  date=date-1},
 http://stackoverflow.com/q/20436820/1281433/doc5=
 {author=http://stackoverflow.com/q/20436820/1281433/author5,
  document=http://stackoverflow.com/q/20436820/1281433/doc5,
  date=date-5}}
```

Comment: Yes.that's good,but as IM using jsf to show the results, I need to organize them in a structure like a list of Hashmap where the keys are(for example), document, author and date and each Hashmap is a row from the table you showed me.But how to know which document corresponds to which property, as I get the results as QuerySolution and when I do QuerySolution.get(document) and QuerySolution.get(author) I get independent results(doenst know  which author belongs to which doc).I have that problem especially because my documents have different amount of author, can be one,more or none.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  When you get the results from Jena as a ResultSet, you get a sequence of rows.  Each row has a binding for `document`, `author`, and `date`.  The `author` and `date` in a row are the ones associated with the `document` in that row.  If you need to copy these results into some other data structure, that's not a problem, but it really doesn't have much to do with Jena or SPARQL, _per se_;  it's just a question of "how to use a HashMap".  Based on your description, it sounds like you want a HashMap with one entry for each row, where the value is a solution.

Comment: @Luciane The ResultSet/QuerySolution API doesn't make it too hard to build up the kind of nested associative structure that it sounds like you're looking for.  I've updated my answer with some code.